# Water heater or a bad breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

The water heater is outside in the utility room and wired to a 60amp double breaker. The breaker inside of the house is tripping but not the breaker outside. I have change both elements to see if that would stop the breaker from tripping but it has not.The energy smart whirlpool  water heater is 17 years old and that was the fist time the elements has been change. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "**a** 60amp double breaker" vs. "breaker inside" vs. "breaker outside"??? Is the 60A breaker in a panel with a lot of other breakers or all by itself? What is the "breaker outside" that isn't tripping?

Comment: Google says Whirlpool EnergySmart is a conventional tanked type: http://www.whirlpoolwaterheaters.com/media/48024/6510306.pdf

Comment: Where did you get the 60A number? Was literal "60" written on a breaker handle?

Comment: Usually if a breaker is tripping it means there's a problem. Sometimes the breaker is the problem but not usually. If there's more than one breaker in series they don't all have to trip.

Comment: Your figures don't make sense.  Typical residential WH run at 4500-5000 W.  Even though they have two elements at that rating each, both don't run at the same time.  60A is more like 14 KW.

Comment: Clear, focused, readable pictures of A) the label of the water heater, B) the "60a double breaker" it's connected to, and C) the "breaker inside the house that's tripping" would be very helpful. Additionally, pictures of the panels with their covers _very carefully_ removed (if you're comfortable doing so) showing the connections to these breakers would be additional bonus material.

Answer (score 1):

Have patience with internet only electricians they most likely have never seen a 12kw water heater,

yes tanked electric.

If this is what you have I would be looking at the elements first they regularly get a pinhole and blow a larger hole creating a short from the center heating to the outer metal,

the models they are talking about are the minimum circuit rating by code but many high end homes do have larger fast recovery water heaters.

There is a chance that you have a standard water heater that was wired to a 60 amp circuit my answer would be the same.

The heating elements are known to trip a main breaker, it’s best to check the elements prior to any damage to the thermostats.